# AWS Glue DynamicFrame split_rows with IN query

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Is it possible to use AWS glue DynamicFrame split_rows function with IN query.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-split_rows

```
frame_to_split = original_dynamic_frame
listOfUUID = initialList
loop start
  split_rows_collection = frame_split.rows({"id": [listOfUUID]}, "contains", "notContains")


  frame_to_process = split_rows_collection.select("contains")

  # Some processing for items in frame that contains listOfUUID's
  # processing frame_to_process

  frame_to_split = split_rows_collection.select("notContains")
  listOfUUID = newList
loop end
```

I have a requirement where I want to loop the dynamicFrame and keep splitting into smaller frames to divide and conquer